# Managing Find and Replace dialog box in MS Word 2010 using Macro

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

The below code display *Find and Replace* dialog box. But the problem is that the *Find* tab and the *Go To* tabs are disabled.
How to keep all the three tabs enabled?

Is it possible to set the *Find* and *Replace* combobox Editable property to `False`?

```
Public Sub EditReplace()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        .Find = "[ ^13^t]{1,};"
        .Replace = ";"
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Find and Replace dialog box]

Comment: What is the purpose of displaying the Dialog if the user cannot edit the fields?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to disable these fields using VBA.

Comment: I am creating a collection of macros that will remove spaces before semicolons,colons,fullstop etc. in order to check the quality of documents.For a particular moment when the user clicks on macro button the `Find and Replace` dialog box will open so while the user finds and replaces, I don't want  `find` and `replace` field to get edited by mistake of user.

Answer (score 1):

Try (with the assumption that "Ctrl H" is still a shortcut for "Replace" in the menu):

```
Public Sub AnotherName()   
       On Error Resume Next
       Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory       
       Selection.Find.Text = "[ ^13^t]{1,};"
       Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = ";"
       SendKeys "+^%H", True
End Sub
```

The name should rather not be "EditReplace", or you will direct here all replace operations in the future.